# ¿Cómo devolver el indice de un arreglo en string?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string, map

Quiero recorrer un array y devolverlo en un String, lo he hecho con flatMap y con map, tambien lo intente con el findIndex, pero sin exito alguno, por ello vengo aquí

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
{
    "affiliate": {
        "groupedServices": {
            "virtual": [{
                "category": [{
                    "active": true,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "service": [
                        "x"
                    ],
                    "menu": [
                        "x"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "name": {
                        "en": "General Medicine (Telemedicine)",
                        "es": "Medicina General (Telemedicina)"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "en": "General Medicine (Telemedicine)",
                        "es": "Medicina General (Telemedicina)"
                    },
                    "updatedBy": "x",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-12T18:29:51.500Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-12T22:23:43.388Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }],
                "subCategory": [],
                "appointmentRequired": false,
                "enabled": true,
                "_id": "x",
                "affiliate": "x",
                "officePhone": "x",
                "place": {
                    "loc": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            -88.01386190000001,
                            15.5038827
                        ]
                    },
                    "enabled": true,
                    "virtual": true,
                    "_id": "x",
                    "country": "x",
                    "countryName": "x",
                    "city": "x",
                    "name": "x",
                    "createdBy": "5f88fad8fbe0752323193758",
                    "address": "x",
                    "createdAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.090Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.090Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "room": "",
                "service": {
                    "active": true,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "affiliateType": [
                        "x"
                    ],
                    "isAppointment": true,
                    "showIsAppointment": false,
                    "isVirtual": true,
                    "isDomicilio": false,
                    "isClinica": false,
                    "_id": "x",
                    "name": {
                        "en": "Telemedicine",
                        "es": "Telemedicina"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "en": "Telemedicine",
                        "es": "Telemedicina"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-12T18:20:38.991Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-13T02:56:48.172Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "price": 500,
                "createdAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.355Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.355Z",
                "__v": 0
            }],
            "atHome": [],
            "clinic": []
        }
    }
}
```

Y quiero acceder al array category del elemento "_id", eso yo lo logro facilmente mapeando el array:

```
service!: any;
this.service = this.bookingModel?.affiliate?.groupedServices.clinic.flatMap(service => service.service._id).toString();
```

Pero me devuelve algo del tipo array: ["x"] y yo quiero que solo me devuelva "x"

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Infinitamente gracias por su ayuda, soy algo lenta para aprender, pero alli voy, incluso en el desvelo para aprender. Muchas Gracias!'

Comment: Creo no logro ver claro lo que deseas hacer, o a que te refieres con infinito, que recibes si es más de un elemento, etc... Pero para llegar al id dentro de category sería algo así, affiliate.groupedServices.virtual[0].category[0]._id. Luego puedes iterar quizás virtual si ahí viene más de uno, y por cada iteración haces un console.log del item. Así recibes solo "x"..
Ejemplo ruta = affiliate.groupedServices.virtual[0].category, luego for(const item of ruta){
console.log(item._id)
}

Comment: Quizás podrías agregar un ejemplo donde haya más de un valor y especificar que valores desearías obtener y como sería el resultado final con esos valores, será más fácil ayudarte. El map justamente devuelve un nuevo array, si bien lo podés usar para iterar, si ya estás dentro de un array, podrías resolverlo con un solo for..

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado estas utilizando flatmap en el ejemplo  porque en este caso? Un ejemplo de uso de flatmap hay que usarlo cuando es necesario en el codigo y si estuvieras utilizando la libreria rxjs seria ademas otro tema Si se recorre adecuadamente se obtiene lo que necesitas ya te respondieron en forma directa como hacerlo pero si lo hicieras con un map  y utilizando correctamente el codigo tambien te muestra x.

let resultadoe=desdeCategory.map(stri=>stri._id).tostring();
Error:

> desdeCategory.map(...).tostring is not a function
>
> let resultado=desdeCategory.map(stri=>stri._id);

> let o=resultado.toString() console.log(o)// x

```js
let sentences = ["Java Array ","Awesome"];
let words = sentences.map(s => s.split(' '));
console.log(words);//[["Java,"Array,""],[Awesome]] 
/*
llet words1 = sentences.flatMap(s => s.split(' '));
console.log(words1);//["Java,·"Array","",Awesome];
*/
   let obj = {
    "affiliate": {
        "groupedServices": {
            "virtual": [{
                "category": [{
                    "active": true,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "service": [
                        "x","y"
                    ],
                    "menu": [
                        "x"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "name": {
                        "en": "General Medicine (Telemedicine)",
                        "es": "Medicina General (Telemedicina)"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "en": "General Medicine (Telemedicine)",
                        "es": "Medicina General (Telemedicina)"
                    },
                    "updatedBy": "x",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-12T18:29:51.500Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-12T22:23:43.388Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }],
                "subCategory": [],
                "appointmentRequired": false,
                "enabled": true,
                "_id": "x",
                "affiliate": "x",
                "officePhone": "x",
                "place": {
                    "loc": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            -88.01386190000001,
                            15.5038827
                        ]
                    },
                    "enabled": true,
                    "virtual": true,
                    "_id": "x",
                    "country": "x",
                    "countryName": "x",
                    "city": "x",
                    "name": "x",
                    "createdBy": "5f88fad8fbe0752323193758",
                    "address": "x",
                    "createdAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.090Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.090Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "room": "",
                "service": {
                    "active": true,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "affiliateType": [
                        "x"
                    ],
                    "isAppointment": true,
                    "showIsAppointment": false,
                    "isVirtual": true,
                    "isDomicilio": false,
                    "isClinica": false,
                    "_id": "x",
                    "name": {
                        "en": "Telemedicine",
                        "es": "Telemedicina"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "en": "Telemedicine",
                        "es": "Telemedicina"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-12T18:20:38.991Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-13T02:56:48.172Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "price": 500,
                "createdAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.355Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-10-16T01:49:39.355Z",
                "__v": 0
            }],
            "atHome": [],
            "clinic": []
        }
    }
}
const ID=  obj.affiliate.groupedServices.virtual[0].category[0]._id;
const desdeCategory= obj.affiliate.groupedServices.virtual[0].category
//console.log(ID)//X;
let resultado=desdeCategory.map(stri=>stri._id)

console.log(resultado.toString())// x
```

Answer (score -2):

Hola @Izlia yo lo haria con map de esta manera:

```
var id;
affiliate.groupedServices.virtual.map(function (cat) {
   cat.category.map(function (item){
      id = item._id;
   });
});
```

De esta manera coges la propiedad virtual que es un array te la recorres, por cada elemento coges el category que es otro array te la reccores y llegas a coger el valor.

Espero que te solucione el problema.

Comment: Dado que usas `map`, si hay varios elementos en el array solo estarás guardando el último dado que iteras sobre *cada* elemento y *machacas* cada vez el valor en id. Funcionará bien mientras solo tenga un único `_id` en el objeto... en el momento en que tenga varios, ya no funcionará. Y si siempre va a tener un único elemento, es una tontería iterar puesto que `affiliate.groupedServices.virtual[0].category[0]._id` es mucho más rápido y directo que iterar.